# JavaFX - How to use an executor to run tasks one at a time?

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to create a Javafx application that takes screenshots from a URL. Where I'm running into issues is with threading. In my main method, I'm trying to run the two screenshots but it's getting stuck after loading the first page. I've tried to wrap the monitorPageStatus() (since it calls the actual saveToPng() function) method in a task that is submitted to the executor (code below). How can I properly submit the task to the executor so both screenshots are taken?

```
public class InsightScreenshot {
   {
         // Clever way to init JavaFX once
         JFXPanel fxPanel = new JFXPanel();
   }
   private Browser browser;
   public Stage stage;
   private Timer timer = new java.util.Timer();

   private ExecutorService exec = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(r -> {
    Thread t = new Thread(r);
    t.setDaemon(true); // allows app to exit if tasks are running
    return t ;
});


   @SuppressWarnings("restriction")
   /**
   * 
    * @param url
   * @param imageName add png extension
   */
   public void showWindow(String url, String imagePath) {
         // JavaFX stuff needs to be done on JavaFX thread
         Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                private Stage window;

                @SuppressWarnings("restriction")
                @Override
                public void run() {
                      Stage window = new Stage();
                      window.setTitle(url);

                      browser = new Browser(url);
                      monitorPageStatus(imagePath, window);

                      VBox layout = new VBox();
                      layout.getChildren().addAll(browser);
                      Scene scene = new Scene(layout);
                      window.setScene(scene);
                      //window.setOnCloseRequest(we -> System.exit(0));
                      window.show();
                }
         });
   }


   private void monitorPageStatus(String imageName, Stage window) {


            timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @SuppressWarnings("restriction")
        public void run() {
            Platform.runLater(() -> {

                if (browser.isPageLoaded()) {

                    System.out.println("Page now loaded, taking screenshot...");
                    saveAsPng(imageName);
                    window.close();
                    cancel();
                } else
                    System.out.println("Loading page...");

            });
        }
    }, 1000, 1000);

   }

   private void saveAsPng(String imageName) {
         WritableImage image = browser.snapshot(new SnapshotParameters(), null);
         //TODO change file path?
         File file = new File(imageName);
         try {
                ImageIO.write(SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(image, null), "png", file);
                System.out.println("Screenshot saved as " + imageName);
         } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
         }
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {


         InsightScreenshot pic = new InsightScreenshot();
         pic.showWindow("ttps://www.google.com", "/images/google.png");

         InsightScreenshot pic2 = new InsightScreenshot();
         pic2.showWindow("https://www.facebook.com", "/images/fb.png");


   }
}
```

Comment: What is `Browser`? I don't understand how the `monitorPageStatus` is supposed to work: doesn't it just test if the page is loaded once, and that's it? So if it's not loaded at the moment you test it, you never call `saveAsPng(...)`?

Comment: Reverted to the TimerTask it was before -- I was just trying to figure out how to wrap it in something that could be submitted to the executor

Comment: JavaFX is a single threaded framework.  Why are you even trying to multi-thread stuff here?  What is Browser?  JavaFX has a [WebEngine](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html), that has a load worker you can listen to state changes on to see when it has finished loading so you can snapshot things.  I don't know why you would try to write some kind of active polling to monitor page status when you can just listen to the state change event and react when the state changes.

Comment: Also why create multiple screenshot objects, why not just create one, provide it with a queue of URLs to screenshot and have it run down the queue taking a snapshot of each URL, then move on to the next one?

Comment: FWIW, here is a link to a [sample for running multiple concurrent tasks](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/5072743) within JavaFX.  That may be helpful to you or just confusing.  The solution to your issue would likely be a bit different because, at most, the only thing that you could run in a parallel JavaFX Task is the saving portion of the snapshot, not the actual rendering of the WebView page and taking of the snapshot as that will occur on the JavaFX thread.  So unless you are saving lots and the save function impacts UI performance, you don't need to save in parallel.